# Why is crossScalaVersion not scalaVersion?

Tags: scala, sbt, cross-build

**build.sbt**

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
```

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.7
```

Then

```
> show scalaVersion
[info] 2.11.4
> show crossScalaVersions
[info] List(2.10.4)
> inspect crossScalaVersions
[info] Setting: scala.collection.Seq[java.lang.String] = List(2.10.4)
[info] Description:
[info]  The versions of Scala used when cross-building.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  */*:crossScalaVersions
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:237
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:crossScalaVersions
[info]  {.}/*:crossScalaVersions
[info]  */*:crossScalaVersions
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:crossScalaVersions
```

It seems like `crossScalaVersions` should be `List(2.11.4)`.

Look at SBT's [source code](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13.7/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L237), that's also what I would think.

```
crossScalaVersions := Seq(scalaVersion.value)
```

Why doesn't `crossScalaVersions` correspond to `scalaVersion`?

Comment: The code you linked to is sbt's default values. Do you have a `crossScalaVersions := List(...)` anywhere in your project ?

Comment: @Marth, no I don't. Then where does the default (for my project) come from?

Comment: @Marth, I added the `inspect`, which shows the value coming from there.

Answer (score 3):

`scalaVersion.value` is context-dependent. So in `Defaults.scala` it's `*/*:scalaVersion` from `appConfiguration.value.provider.scalaProvider`. It's the version used to compile your project's definition, including your `build.sbt` file (sbt `0.13.7` uses `2.10.4` scala-compiler to compile your project definitions). And that the only way as your project's definitions (including `scalaVersion`) isn't compiled yet when `Defaults` executed and `crossScalaVersions` defined. So, `*/*:crossScalaVersions` depends on `*/*:scalaVersion` not `proj/*:scalaVersion`.

Just compare `Provided by` with explicit `scalaVersion := 2.11.4` inside `build.sbt`:

```
> inspect scalaVersion
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = 2.11.4
[info] Description:
[info]  The version of Scala used for building.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/user/dev/proj/}proj/*:scalaVersion
[info] Defined at:
[info]  /Users/user/dev/proj/build.sbt:1
[info] Reverse dependencies (D=derives):
[info]    *:allDependencies
[info]  D *:scalaBinaryVersion
[info]    *:libraryDependencies
[info]    *:scalaInstance
[info]    *:crossScalaVersions
[info]    *:update
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:scalaVersion
[info]  {.}/*:scalaVersion
[info]  */*:scalaVersion
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:scalaVersion
```

And without one (just empty project):

```
> inspect scalaVersion
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = 2.10.4
[info] Description:
[info]  The version of Scala used for building.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  */*:scalaVersion
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:232
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  *:allDependencies
[info]  *:libraryDependencies
[info]  *:update
[info]  *:scalaInstance
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:scalaVersion
[info]  {.}/*:scalaVersion
[info]  */*:scalaVersion
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:scalaVersion
```

So, you just need to redefine `*/*:scalaVersion` in your `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion in GlobalScope := "2.11.2"
```

Comment: They've dramatically changed API - so now they use macros `.value` for keys evaluation instead of `crossScalaVersions in GlobalScope <<= Seq(scalaVersion).join`, so it was previously dependent on nearest `scala-version`. Now it depends on scalaVersion in GlobalScope, so you can just put `scalaVersion in GlobalScope := "2.11.2"` inside your `buid.sbt` to fix problem